# Do these facts about $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ generalize to more general cases?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, injective-module

We know that $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} $ is injective. Not only that $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ is exact iff $0 \to Hom(C,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) \to Hom(B,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})\to Hom(A,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) \to 0$ is exact.

My question is :

> Do these statements hold good if $\mathbb{Z}$ is replaced by a general domain $R$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ is replaced by the quotient field $Q$ of $R$ ?

It is easy to see that $Q/Z$ is injective if $R$ is a PID and hence the exactness of the first sequence implies the exactness of the second, but the reverse implication is not clear.

Comment: It also holds for Dedekind domains. I suspect amongst commutative noetherian domains, it is only the Dedekind domains.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a notion of *injective cogenerator* of the category $\mathrm{Mod}$-$R$: An injective cogenerator is an injective $R$-module $C$ such that for every nonzero $R$-module $M$, there is a nonzero homomorphism $M\rightarrow C$, i.e. $\mathrm{Hom}_R(M,C)\neq 0$.

As it turns out, injective cogenerators are precisely the modules satisfying the property you are interested in.

See the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229168/injective-cogenerators-in-the-category-of-modules-over-a-noetherian-ring) for the fact that injective cogenerators have the property you are interested in, i.e. the functor $\mathrm{Hom}_R(-,C)$ preserves and reflects exact sequences.

Conversely, assume that $C$ is an $R$-module such that $\mathrm{Hom}_R(-,C)$ preserves and reflects exact sequences. Then $C$ is injective. It remains to show that $C$ is a cogenerator.

Let $M$ be an $R$-module. Consider a sequence
$$0\rightarrow 0 \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0.$$

Applying $\mathrm{Hom}_R(-,C)$, we obtain a sequence 
$$0\rightarrow\mathrm{Hom}_R(M,C) \rightarrow \mathrm{Hom}_R(0,C) \rightarrow \mathrm{Hom}_R(0,C) \rightarrow 0 \;\;. $$

If $\mathrm{Hom}_R(M,C)=0$, the latter sequence is exact, so the former sequence is exact. Thus, $M=0$.

Now, in the commutative Noetherian ring case, there is a structure theorem saying that every injective module is a direct sum of indecomposable injective modules, which are of the form $E(R/P)$, where $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$ and $E(-)$ denotes taking the injective hull. From this it follows that the module

$$\bigoplus_{P \in m\mathrm{Spec}(R)}E(R/P)$$

is an injective cogenerator.

In the PID case, it can be verified that for $p \in R$ a prime, the injective hull $E(R/pR)$ is, up to isomorphism, the submodule $R[(1/p)]/R$ of $Q/R$ (with the module $R/pR$ embedded via $r+pR \mapsto \frac{r}{p}+R$; also note that if $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $p$ is a prime, this gives you an isomorphic copy of the Prüfer group $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\infty}}$). Thus, we have

$$Q/R=\left(\sum_{pR \in m\mathrm{Spec}(R)}R[(1/p)]\right)/R=\sum_{pR \in m\mathrm{Spec}(R)}\left(R[(1/p)]/R\right)$$

and it is easily seen (from $R$ being UFD) that the sum is direct. So the module $Q/R$ is indeed an injective cogenerator in this case.

Comment: Very nice answer!